# Does Swift support string block?

Tags: string, swift

Languages such as Ruby and Python both support string block. Such as:

```
a = '''
  Hello
  World
'''
```

Does Swift support string block?

Comment: If you need long strings like this in your code, consider [strings files](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html). As a bonus, using strings files for user-visible text makes internationalization much, much less painful down the road.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. As outlined in the Lexical Structure of the Swift programming language introduction, [string literals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-XID_860) are enclosed within one single pair of quotes and must not contain newlines.

The grammar specifies that:

> string-literal → " quoted-text "
>   quoted-text → quoted-text-item quoted-text opt
>   quoted-text-item → escaped-character
>   quoted-text-item → ( expression )
>   quoted-text-item → Any Unicode extended grapheme cluster except " , \ , U+000A, or U+000D
>   [...]

Where U+000A and U+000D are newline and carriage return characters, respectively.

At the moment, there is no other kind of *string-literal*.